# Finding Common Duplicates in Arrays

Tags: arrays, duplicates

I have two integer arrays with no info on range of the elements in the arrays. All i know is the lengths of two arrays m and n. Now there are some duplicates in both the arrays. I want to find the lowest common duplicate from both the arrays. Assume that i have limited memory, how do i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be MergeSort Algorithm can help you for solving this problem. MergeSort Algorithm is basically for sorting the elements in a list but its main crux is in its Divide and Conquer Approach. As you have mentioned that the memory is limited, hence Divide and Conquer seems to be a reasonable approach for solving the problem.

Comment: Merge sort requires extra space for sorting in the merge procedure. So in this problem i would require 2 intermediate arrays for sorting the original arrays. But even after sorting how can we identify the common duplicates from both the arrays? Can we do without consuming any more buffers?

Comment: What you said is true in context of Sorting, but as you mentioned, you are looking for duplicates and hence just checking whether a given element in array 1 is present in array 2. Hence I do not think you would be requiring more buffers.

Comment: I would like to clarify that the arrays are not sorted initially. So are you saying to sort the arrays and check element in array1 is present in array2?

Answer (score 0):

one possible method (NB! there are probably more efficient ways for doing this both memory and performance wise).

1. create two `map` instances A and B for first and second array. `key` is the integer and `value` is the integer count in the respective array.
2. count the number of occurrences of each integer in both arrays and store them in maps A and B accordingly
3. remove the `(key,value)` pairs where value is less than 2 in both A and B
4. take the keysets of both A and B and find the intersection.
5. find the lowest key in the intersection, which is the answer

Comment: I understood the steps, but how do we remove the key,value pairs if we have a static hashtable. Not sure how much performance issue will be raised when deleting from a hashtable? or Does it mean that this problem depends on a dynamic hashtable?

Comment: Instead of the removal step actually we could just traverse the hash table and collect the keys into a set, where value>=2 and then discard the hashtable entirely.